# Storing XML files google app engine

Tags: xml, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, storage, google-cloud-storage

Just started learning about google cloud platform.

I've read about the google cloud storage that it was impossible to modify stored files unless i overwrite them.

I would like to store xml files which are frequently modified.

Is there another possibility to store and modify xml files in Google the google cloud platform ?

Comment: Because i need to append to the files frequently, wouldn't it be a problem when the files become important in term of size ?, imagine having to rewrite everything everytime with an additional content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to store the data in a database. I prefer NoSQL databases such as `Cloud DataStore`, but you can choose as per your preference. Google Cloud Storage is a possibility if you're keen on keeping data in files (although it's a bad design). I wouldn't prefer `GCS` since it's slower to fetch and save data in it than storing it in Datastore. If you don't need to search the data then you can, in fact, store the complete XML string as a `TextProperty` in Datastore too. I have saved complete JSON strings into `Datastore` and it's much faster than accessing GCS buckets in App Engine.

Another alternative would be to use `Compute Engine`, instead of `App Engine` for saving the file inside the instance, although this would lead to problems if you try to scale the app to more than one instance.

Comment: Thanks (y), i'll try to structure my xml file in the Datastore as you said, i think it's kinda good idea since json file is well-structured too :D

Answer (score 0):

How often are you going to overwrite them? If they're fairly large (>a megabyte or so) and you want to update them more frequently than every few seconds, GCS is probably not going to be the best choice, not because it won't work, but because there will likely be faster and less bandwidth-intense options then rapidly editing a large XML file and rewriting it. There are a whole lot of options depending on what your program needs:

- Writing a series of "deltas" to record small changes and crunching them together later.
- Keep the data in Cloud Datastore or Cloud Bigtable or Cloud SQL or something else that allows quick, structured changes.
- Using something like Persistant Disk to get more of an "editing files" interface.

Plus many other, more custom solutions. It depends entirely on the needs of your program.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What i really want to do is to save the conversation between two persons inside a well-formed xml file, i don't want to stock the conversation inside the database. Is there any way ? or any other option you can suggest me ?